# tf.GradientTape giving None gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gradient

I'm trying to write a custom training loop. After creating the model, I have added some extra trainable parameter to some layers of my model. I have used these extra parameters to update my original parameter on every forward pass. But when I'm calculating the gradient, it's giving None for the extra parameter that i have added last. Code is given below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1,1)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.layers[1].add_weight(name="x1", shape=(1,), initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(value=1.0),trainable=True)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((feature, labels))

for i, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(dataset):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        for par in model.layers[1].trainable_weights:
            if "x1" in par.name:
                bits = tf.convert_to_tensor(par)
        for par in model.layers[1].trainable_weights:
            if "kernel" in par.name:
                par = bits + 1.0    
        x = model(x_batch_train, training = True)
        loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(y_batch_train, x)
        val = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
        for v in val:
            print(v)
```

Here, I have added one extra parameter called `x1` and it's updating the `kernel` of Dense layer. But I'm getting None gradient for `x1` parameter. The output is:

```
tf.Tensor([[0.]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([-0.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
None
tf.Tensor([[0. 0.]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([-0.5  0.5], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

Why it's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the changes you are making to the layer's weights have no direct connection to the output of the model in the context of `tf.GradientTape` and are therefore not tracked. You could solve this with a simple custom layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class DenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=1):
        super(DenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.units = units
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight("kernel",
                              shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
                                      self.units], trainable=True)
        self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,), initializer="zeros", trainable=True)
        self.bits = self.add_weight(name="x1", shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
                                      self.units], initializer=tf.keras.initializers.ones(), trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, (self.w + self.bits + 1.0)) + self.b)

dense_layer = DenseLayer(1)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1,1)))
model.add(dense_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random.normal((50, 1, 1)), tf.random.uniform((50, ), maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32))).batch(2)
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
for i, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(dataset):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y = model(x_batch_train, training = True)
        loss = loss_fn(y_batch_train, y)
        val = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
        for v in val:
            print(v)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(val, model.trainable_variables))
```

Comment: If I print `model.summary()` for the code that you have given, it shows 6 total and trainable params. Shouldn't it be seven?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it would not work like that..because self.bits still does not affect the output..see updated answer.

Comment: In my case, I just want to use `self.bits` to update the value of `self.w`. Is there any way to do this and make the bits parameter trainable? I'm trying to convert a pytorch project to tensorflow. They did `module._parameters[param_name] = bits`, I'm trying to achieve same thing.

Comment: I understand but there will still be no gradients for bits because it does not directly affect the input to the layer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One last question. Can I do this to the layers of a previously created model without creating custom layers? I mean, if i take a model as a input and do this to all of it's layers.

Comment: Haven’t tried it but I don’t see why not

Answer (score -1):

Your idea is good I didn't extend from the last answer but this question is asked once about the custom layer and that you can do it for lstm by training as model.fit( ... )

It is not about the Gradient Tape.

**[ Sample - Dense ]:**

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Function
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs, num_add):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        self.num_add = num_add
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.num_outputs])

    def call(self, inputs):
        temp = tf.add( inputs, self.num_add )
        temp = tf.matmul(temp, self.kernel)
        return temp

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 4 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
])

layer = MyDenseLayer(10, 5)

model.add(layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

**[ Output ]:**

[image: Sample]

Comment: So, do i have to add extra custom layer for the task? And also, if I want to do this after creating the model, how can i place these extra layers between existing layers?

Comment: Your question is to update the values to a custom layer from my example you can update its scopes and manage it as a layer when the model initialize. You may add a few-layer or may bot that depends on the objective.